# Suggestion regarding models

Tags: django, django-models

I need your suggestion. I am creating a model named `PlayList` where user's can add `songs` and `movies` in his `playlist`.
 I've added a field name `playlist_type`. It will ask the user's is it song playlist or movies playlist? If it is song playlist so he can't add `movies` in playlist.

Ok. Now should I use ContenType or Should I create two more seperate models `PlayListSong` and `PlayListMovies`. What do you suggest? Thanks

```
class PlayList(TimeStampedModel):
    SONG_PLAYLIST = 1
    MOVIES_PLAYLIST = 2

    PLAYLIST_CHOICES = (
        (SONG_PLAYLIST, 'Songs'),
        (MOVIES_PLAYLIST, 'Movies'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(_('PlayList Name'), max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    playlist_type = models.IntegerField(choices=PLAYLIST_CHOICES)

class PlayListContentType(TimeStampedModel):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(PlayList)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name="likes")
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are better off creating separate models, PlayListSong and PlayListMovies, that are inherited from the PlayList model.

If you go with the PlayListContentType model, you will likely have to perform an if/else check in every function you define that first determines what content_type you are dealing with before doing anything with it...

...for [a very simple] example:

```
class PlayListContentType(TimeStampledModel):
    // Attributes here.

    def get_favorite_movie(self):
      if self.content_type.name == "movie":
          // Get movie from playlist.
      else:
          // Return error message/exception/etc.
```

This is just one of the drawbacks that immediately comes to mind.  You can code/design around it - but if you are immediately forcing restrictions like this on yourself, then you are setting yourself up for failure down the road (what happens when you want to support a new content type?).

Comment: Ok Thanks I'll create separate models. :-)